# exception in gwt hibernate program

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gwt, rpc

I am trying to make a simple GWT RPC Hibernate program that adds a user to MySQL database. I am using Eclipse EE. The application is successfully adding user to database but it raises exception when compiled. 
Here is the exception & source of my application.

**exception:**

```
Exception in thread "UnitCacheLoader" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.readObject(DiskCacheToken.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.loadUnitMap(PersistentUnitCache.java:493)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$000(PersistentUnitCache.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$UnitCacheMapLoader.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:154)
    ... 16 more
```

**entrypoint class:**

```
package rpctest.client;

import rpctest.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Rpctest implements EntryPoint {

    final TextBox firstName = new TextBox();
    final TextBox lastName = new TextBox();
    final Button ans = new Button("Add User");
    final Label label1 = new Label("First Name");
    final Label label2 = new Label("Last Name");
    //final Label errorLabel = new Label();
    private VerticalPanel mainpanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private final RpctestServiceAsync calNumbers = GWT
            .create(RpctestService.class);

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        addpanel1.add(label1);
        addpanel1.add(firstName);
        addpanel2.add(label2);
        addpanel2.add(lastName);
        mainpanel.add(addpanel1);
        mainpanel.add(addpanel2);
        mainpanel.add(ans);

        ans.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            String name1 = firstName.getValue();    
            String name2 = lastName.getValue();

            calNumbers.addUser(name1,name2,
                new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // Show the RPC error message to the user
                        Window.alert("check your inputs");
                    }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Window.alert("User is ->"+result);
                }
            });}
        });
        // We can add style names to widgets
        //sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

        // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
        // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element

        /*RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
         * 
        RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
        RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);*/
        RootPanel.get().add(mainpanel);

    }
}
```

**interfaces:**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("testService")
public interface RpctestService extends RemoteService {

    String addUser(String firstName,String lastName) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}


package rpctest.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface RpctestServiceAsync {

    void addUser(String firstName, String lastName,
            AsyncCallback<String> callback);

}
```

**service Implementation class:**

```
package rpctest.server;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import hibDomain.User;
import rpctest.client.RpctestService;

public class RpctestServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet  implements RpctestService {

        public String addUser(String name1, String name2)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

              Transaction trns = null;
              Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
              try {
               trns = session.beginTransaction();

               User user = new User();

               user.setFirstName(name1);
               user.setLastName(name2);

               session.save(user);

               session.getTransaction().commit();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if(trns != null){
                trns.rollback();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
              } finally{
               session.flush();
               session.close();
              }

            return name1; 
    }

}
```

**pojo class:**

```
package hibDomain;

public class User {
 private Integer id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

**mapping file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="hibDomain.User" table="users" >
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstName">
   <column name="first_name" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastName">
   <column name="last_name"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**cfg file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <!-- Database connection settings -->
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdata</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password"></property>

  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <!-- Mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>


 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Util class:**

```
package rpctest.server;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  try {
   // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
   // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
   System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }
 }
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

Comment: The exception you have pasted has stack trace only from Java.io or com.google packages, meaning libraries or system source. Could you append the stack trace from that part which points to some class that you have written and then paste source code of that too. That will give some leads

Comment: @enterprize Do you get the exception even when you don't explicitly close the session?

Comment: @Darthenius: exception is raised when program is compiled.

Comment: @ vishal.biyani: How can I expand the append the stack trace? I already pasted complete source code.

Comment: I do not know what happened but its now working perfectly. I just experimented by shuffling suspected files to different folders & consequently changed references & when come back again to original structure when that was when I posted this question was posted, it stop raising any exception eventually. May be something was missing/wrong in some path. Thank you all for your interest in my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exception in GWT RPC app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521475/exception-in-gwt-rpc-app)

Answer (score 6):

This unlikely to be related to running out of disk space.

Much more likely you either built as a different user or for some other reason there are existing, invalid, temporary files which are causing the problem.

Look in your GWT dir for the directories "gwt-unitCache", and "reports". Delete them. Then run ant clean, ant test; that should solve the problem~

Almost certainly the reason it 'suddenly started worked' was you did something like a fresh git clone or cleared out the directory, deleting these files. :)

Answer (score 4):

Delete ./src/main/**gwt-unitCache**.

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of disk space.
GWT compiler could not find temp space.