# Getting Unitcahche exception while running the GWT application

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, caching

I am getting unitcache exception when I run the GWT application in Eclipse.

I do not understand why it is coming...I also delete the cache files and deploy folder from war folder and compiled the application but it did not worked...

I also restarted the eclipse IDE and tried but result is same it stopped to the "loadCompleteLatch.countDown();" line from PersistentUnitCache.java file...

following is the exception what I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "UnitCacheLoader" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.readObject(DiskCacheToken.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.loadUnitMap(PersistentUnitCache.java:493)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$000(PersistentUnitCache.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$UnitCacheMapLoader.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2675)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:154)
    ... 16 more
```

Let me know if anyone knows solution...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution..... I just deleted gwt-unitCache folder from my project folder, [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521475/exception-in-gwt-rpc-app) suggested by [enterprize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701854/enterprize)...

Thanks to him