# Failure in unit cache map load - GWT

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-errors, intellij-idea, smartgwt

I get this error during compile-time of my GWT project, there is no such folder as 'gwt-UnitCache' to delete, as suggested in the following questions

- [Weird GWT compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648657/weird-gwt-compile-error)
- [exception in GWT RPC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521475/exception-in-gwt-rpc-app)

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA (IDE), SmartGWT EE (Framework), JBoss AS (Server) and JPA

Here's the error log:

[image]

Comment: Share the stack trace. It might be a issu with idea gwt plugin and not exactly related to GWT.

Comment: Added the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by systematically removing, compiling and re-adding every artifact piece.
If you're having this problem, make sure you have a structure like this:

[image]

**lib** contains your compile-time libraries

Answer (score 4):

If you change the value of your `<module rename-to='<appname>'>` in .gwt.xml it will give the same error :) but then you can just delete your `gwt-unitCache` and all is ok :)

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA stores GWT cache files in other location than `<ProjectFolder>/gwt-unitCache`, which is a default directory for a cache if you are using, for example, Eclipse with GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse).

In IDEA, GWT cache should be located by default at `<your_home>/.IntelliJIdea12/system/gwt` (IntelliJ IDEA 12, Linux). For other operating systems you can check [Project and IDE Settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html).

If you delete mentioned `gwt` folder contents, IntelliJ will create a new cache, which in turn might solve your `Failure in unit cache...` (and similar `Unable to read from byte cache`) problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Eclipse.

Unfortunately looks like the only solution is the one given by Crowlix.
I tried to delete gwtCache and Temp files, but nothing worked.

The problem only got fixed when deleting the entire project and re-importing it.

Comment: I got it fixed clearing the GWT cache in temp files , guess people can try giving it a shot

Answer (score 1):

I am face off this same error, this tip doesn't works for me, moreover, I keep about looking for a solution, and finally, I got this advice:

[Java stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127262)

I tried with -Xss1m, but the error persists, I keep on trying, my final value was -Xss5m

I am using GWT 2.5.1 and IntelliJ 12.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm sure both answers will be very useful for quite some people =)

Comment: fixed it for me, on a project with 150K LOC + Sencha GXT

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem building a project with **maven**.

Usign both suggestion of [Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven) and @iVieL:

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss32m"
$ mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

you must clean your project first (Project -> Clean)
then remove /gwt-unitCache
then rebuild it.